# OpenGL glOrtho set up match the window size

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am a beginner in OpenGl and I am struggling a bit with setting up the glOrtho camera to match the window size so that I can draw a line using the window's coordinates. For example, if I want to draw a line from coordinates 0,10 (x,y) to 600,10. I managed to draw the line (which will be a "Separator" from the viewport and a toolbar with buttons) in my current set up but it was by "try end error" approach and the coordinates that I needed to put don't make any sense to me. When I tried to draw a line using the above-mentioned coordinates, the line simply did not show up. What I need to change in the glOrtho set up in order to work with these (1000x600) screen size and draw my vertices and not these:

```
glVertex3f(-2.0, 11.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(20.0, 11.0, 0.0);
```

Note, my current window size is 1000x600 (width/height)

This is the line (on the top that crosses the whole screen):
[image]

This is my OGWindow class that handles all of the drawing:

```
void OGWindow::MyReSizeGLScene(int fwidth, int fheight) 
{
// Store window size  in class variables so it can be accessed in myDrawGLScene() if necessary
wWidth = fwidth;
wHeight = fheight;

// Calculate aspect ration of the OpenGL window
aspect_ratio = (float) fwidth / fheight;

// Set camera so it can see a square area of space running from 0 to 10 
// in both X and Y directions, plus a bit of space around it.
Ymin = -1;
Ymax = 12;
Xmin = -1;

// Choose Xmax so that the aspect ration of the projection
// = the aspect ratio of the viewport
Xmax = (aspect_ratio * (Ymax -Ymin)) + Xmin;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);        // Select The Projection Stack
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax, -1.0, 1.0);

glViewport(0, 0, wWidth, wHeight);      // Viewport fills the window
}

void OGWindow::myDrawGLScene(GLvoid)        // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the drawing area

OGWindow::myDrawModel();
drawToolbar();

glutSwapBuffers(); // Needed if we're running an animation
glFlush();
}



void OGWindow::myDrawModel(GLvoid)
{
switch ( squareColour ) {
case RED:
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    break;
case BLUE:
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    break;
}

glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex3f( squareX, squareY, 0.0 ); // Coordinates of bottom-left corner of square
    glVertex3f( squareX + squareWidth, squareY, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( squareX + squareWidth, squareY + squareHeight, 0.0 );
    glVertex3f( squareX, squareY + squareHeight, 0.0 );
glEnd();
}


// Convert from screen coords returned by mouse
// to world coordinates.
// Return result in worldX, worldY
void OGWindow::screen2World(int screenX, int screenY, double & worldX, double & worldY)
{
// Dimensions of rectangle viewed by camera projection
double projWidth = Xmax -Xmin;
double projHeight = Ymax - Ymin;

// Screen coords with origin at bottom left
int screenLeft = screenX;
int screenUp = wHeight - screenY; 

worldX = Xmin + screenLeft * projWidth / wWidth ;
worldY = Ymin + screenUp *  projHeight / wHeight ;
}

//Method to draw the toolbar separator line
void OGWindow::drawToolbar(GLvoid) {
//draw toolbar line separator
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(-2.0, 11.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(20.0, 11.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
//draw create button

glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(2.0, 10.0, 0.0);

    glutSolidCube(2.0);
glPopMatrix();

}
```

This is my main class where I am ivoking the methods from OGWindow:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);   
glutInitWindowSize( 1000, 600 );
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Demo");
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // enable the depth buffer test

glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene);
glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);
glutMouseFunc(mouseClick);
glutMotionFunc(mouseMotion);
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mousePassiveMotion);
glutIdleFunc(Idle);
theWindow.initGL(); 

glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix using `glLoadIdentity`? Also you don't swap the `glMatrixMode` back to `GL_MODELVIEW` after resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So, first** your ortho settings. If you want your camera to match the screen dimensions, glOrtho has to use the same dimensions.

```
// This will anchor the camera to the center of the screen
// Camera will be centered on (0,0)
glOrtho( -screenWidth/2.f, screenWidth/2.f, -screenHeight/2.f, screenHeight/2.f, -1, 1 );

// This will anchor the camera to the lower left corner of the screen
// Camera will be centered on (screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)
glOrtho( 0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, -1, 1 );
```

Try both and see the difference. Although if you are making some sort of editor, where your camera doesn't move, you may be looking for the second ortho setup.

**Second**, you only ever use (apparently) the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix mode. You must use this mode to set the camera projection and `GL_MODELVIEW` to apply transforms to the camera or the objects.

So when you call resize and don't change the matrix mode back to `GL_MODELVIEW`, you'll be applying translations to the projection matrix.

If you did forget to initialize the modelview matrix it may contain garbage values and yield unexpected results.

Comment: I tested the suggestions and they are working as you mentioned here. Thank you for the detailed explanation on my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [documentation of glOrtho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) function. As you see, there are 6 parameters: *left, right, bottom, top, near, far*. You made mistake by setting window width to *top* instead of *bottom* parameter. Here's proper use of  function:

```
glOrtho (0, 1000, 600, 0, -1.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I will have a thorough look at the documentation and I will try out your suggestion when I get home. Allure your help.

Comment: Thank you very much. That set the scene exactly how I needed to be. :)